# Sed: how to replace a complex string

Tags: linux, replace, sed

File `nls_test.pl` contains a line: `$sel->click("//button[text()='OK']");`
I want to replace the string 
`//button[text()='OK']` with this string

```
//button[text()='".$sel->get_resource_value("oracle.sysman.resources.CommonResourceBundle", "OK")."']
```

I have tried:

```
sed -i".bak" 's#"//button[text()='OK']"#"//button[text()='".$sel->get_resource_value("oracle.sysman.resources.CommonResourceBundle", "OK")."']"#g' nls_test.pl
```

I got: `sel: Undefined variable`

Then I tried:

```
sed -i".bak" 's#"//button[text()='OK']"#"//button[text()='".\$sel->get_resource_value("oracle.sysman.resources.CommonResourceBundle", "OK")."']"#g' nls_test.pl
```

The result is the same: `sel: Undefined variable`.

Could you tell me how to do it? Thank you!

Comment: Is `perl` an option? If so, try its `quotemeta()` function. You will avoid the hell of escaping all special characters.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed -i -e "s@//button\[text()='OK'\]\"@//button\[text()='\".\$sel->get_resource_value(\"oracle.sysman.resources.CommonResourceBundle\", \"OK\").\"']@g" nls_test.pl
```

Answer (score 1):

This is crazy stuff, this should work though

```
x='".\$sel->get_resource_value("oracle.sysman.resources.CommonResourceBundle", "OK")."'
sed -i.bak "s~\$sel->click(\"\(//button\[text()='\)OK\('\)\]\");~\1$x\2]~" file
```